# Making a trivial Qt list model with constant strings

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn Qt's MVC model by designing my own custom list model that just returns 10 rows containing the text "Testing"  and view this in a QListView. But when I try running it, no items are shown in the ListView. I guess I have misunderstood something fundamental here but can't figure out what it is.

The source for the model is:

testmodel.h:

```
#define TESTMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class TestModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QModelIndex sibling(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &idx) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // TESTMODEL_H
```

testmodel.cpp:

```
#include "testmodel.h"

TestModel::TestModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{

}

int TestModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return 10;
}

QVariant TestModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return QString("Testing");
}

QModelIndex TestModel::sibling(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &idx) const
{
    if (!idx.isValid() || column != 0 || row >= 10)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(row, 0);
}
```

In the constructor of the main window:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    TestModel *tm = new TestModel(this);
    ui->listView->setModel(tm);
}
```

If I change this to instead create a QStringListModel populated with strings, I can see the strings inside.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104711/qlistview-with-qabstractlistmodel-shows-an-empty-list

Comment: Testing for role in the data method as suggested in the linked post fixed the problem - thanks.